# Java program can not find a file that's been just created in a shell script

Tags: java, file, shell, echo, output

I am running a shell script from Java program and in that shell script I am echoing its output to a text file, and in the same Java program I am trying to read that newly created text file. However it can not find the file because the file is somehow not being created instantly. How can I make java wait until the file is created?
Here is the part of Java code that reads a file:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     TreeMap <String, Long> myMap = new TreeMap <String, Long>();
     Scanner scanner = null;
     int runtime = 0; 

     //populate the map
     myMap.put("key", value);
     myMap.put("key", value);

     List<String> cmdList = new ArrayList<String>();
     cmdList.add("/path/to/my/shell/script/shellscript.sh");
     for(Map.Entry entry : myMap.entrySet())
     {
        cmdList.add(entry.getKey().toString());
        cmdList.add(entry.getValue().toString());
     }
     try
     {
       Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdList.toArray(new String[cmdList.size()]));
       File file = new File("/path/to/my/text/file/output.txt");
       scanner = new Scanner(file);
       while (scanner.hasNextInt())
       {
            runtime = scanner.nextInt();
       }

     }
     catch (IOException ex){ System.out.println("Could not read the output." + ex.getMessage()); }
     System.out.println(runtime);
  }
```

here's the shell script:

```
    i=0
    args=("$@")
    while [ $i -lt $# ]
    do
    START = `date +%s`
       some operation here

    done


    echo $END - $START | bc >> output.txt
```

Comment: A better question might be: How can I make java wait until the file is created, or set a handler to run when it is created?

Comment: Could you post your Java and Shell codes?

Answer (score 0):

My simple Java code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class WaitForFileSystem {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        File file = new File("someFile.txt");

        System.out.println("Start:" + file + " " + file.exists());

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(".../workspace/.../batch.sh");
        System.out.println("Processing: " + file + " " + file.exists());

        int returnCode = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("End:" + file + " " + file.exists());
        }

}
```

With my simple Shell skript:

```
echo hello > someFile.txt
```

Makes this output:

```
Start:someFile.txt false
Processing: someFile.txt true
End:someFile.txt true
```

Is this also the way, that you are doing your system call? Did you include a `p.waitFor();` in your code?

Comment: so p.waitFor() means I should wait for the process to finish, in my case to create the file, and then I can read that file right?

Comment: Exactly. I think you should try to add `process.waitFor()` in your code.